# SQL Replication to msaccess database

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2003

We have an application which uses the SQL master database in a central server. And now we want to use the application in the offline basis as well. So I want to replicate the SQL database to the ms access database on user click.

On connection to the sqlserver user is asked if he/she wants to replicate for the offline use.

Is it possible via the replication technique provided by SQL server or has to be done by any other means.
Can you suggest any?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not replicate to a SQL Server database?

Comment: Yes, _SQL Server_ in the _Express_ version can act as a replication slave.